# What is the most an adversary can do in the context of public key masquerading?

Tags: rsa, public-key, cryptanalysis

Suppose two parties A and B are using a public-key encryption scheme in order to communicate securely. A and B both have a public/private key pair:

$$ A: (P_A, S_A), B: (P_B, S_B)$$

and A already knows about B's public key but has no proof of authenticity.
What is the most an adversary C can do while impersonating one of the parties (we assume there is no authentication employed). For example, if C masquerades as B and creates a key pair:

$$ C(P_B, S_C) $$

he may be able to trick A into sending it encrypted messages with the public key of B, but not more since not being in possession of B's secret key C cannot retrieve the message from A. But what more can C do from this point with retrieving the secret key of B? In a more concrete setting, how can the RSA scheme be exploited as mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the situation should be concretized a little.

> A and B both have a public/private key pair:

Does A already know $P_B$, and vice versa? If not, then $C$ can send to A the $P_C$ saying it's «$P_B$» (similar for B, $P_C$ substitutes $P_A$), and become a typical man-in-the-middle, being able to, for example, remove any «real» message from B to A (something he can perform without keys at all) and decrypt or even modify everything that A sends to «B».

> but not more since not being in possession of B's secret key C cannot retrieve the message from A.

Hypothetically, if A is «naive» enough (may A be a machine, for instance?), C sends him the message like «stop using my public key $P_B$, instead use $P_C$» (encrypted with $P_A$), A decrypts it with $S_A$, believes without approvals, switches to $P_C$, and then C becomes a man-in-the-middle again.

Does A know $S_B$? Obviously, he must not; otherwise, using the preceding trick, C *may* convince A to share $S_B$, and impersonate B elsewhere.

In general, the «exploitability» here depends not only on the cleverness of C, but on the «naivety» of A and B as well (they have to know what's dangerous and don't do it).

> do from this point with retrieving the secret key of B?

Didn't you mean *without* retrieving?

Sorry if this looks like a comment. In case you consider a man-in-the-middle attack to be «the most an adversary can do» (or at least critical), it probably helps to concretize the picture. Also, although it is stated that

> assume there is no authentication employed

to avoid man-in-the-middle attack is a kind of authentication, in itself.

When the situation is clarified, other answers will be much more useful, and this one may be deleted.

Comment: A knows about B's public key but the key itself is not authenticated so C can claim to be B.